# Windows 10 crashing several times, specially when waking it up

Tags: windows-10, bsod, dell-latitude

My work laptop is a Dell Latitude 3540 with Windows 10, I already reinstalled Windows several times and the problem persists.

This laptop model has a common problem related to Intel Management Engine Interface (IMEI) where if you use the version 10.x installed by Windows it freezes after going on sleep mode. If you install IMEI 9.x the sleep mode works but the computer seems to work slower and if you install version 11.x (my current scenario) it also works, seems to be a little faster than 9.x, however none of these versions solve the crash error. Though I'm not sure if it is the cause of the crashes.

I installed BlueScreenView from NirSoft and got this report https://gist.github.com/julianonunes/1ac3602ebe0722d7cf754585a9e5e19f

Here is the output of WinDbg too:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.10240.9 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.




Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP]
Kernel Bitmap Dump File: Kernel address space is available, User address space may not be available.




************* Symbol Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       SRV*C:\SymCache*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Symbol search path is: SRV*C:\SymCache*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
No .natvis files found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\Visualizers.
Windows 10 Kernel Version 10586 MP (4 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Built by: 10586.420.amd64fre.th2_release_sec.160527-1834
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff803`c2684000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff803`c2962cf0
Debug session time: Tue Jul  5 15:17:55.891 2016 (UTC - 3:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 8:03:48.713
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
...............................................................
Loading User Symbols
PEB is paged out (Peb.Ldr = 00000054`8137f018).  Type ".hh dbgerr001" for details
Loading unloaded module list
.........
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************



Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.



BugCheck 139, {3, ffffd000255f84d0, ffffd000255f8428, 0}



Page 1c0 not present in the dump file. Type ".hh dbgerr004" for details
Page 1c0 not present in the dump file. Type ".hh dbgerr004" for details
Page 1c0 not present in the dump file. Type ".hh dbgerr004" for details
Page 1c0 not present in the dump file. Type ".hh dbgerr004" for details
Page 1c0 not present in the dump file. Type ".hh dbgerr004" for details
Page 1c0 not present in the dump file. Type ".hh dbgerr004" for details
Page 1c0 not present in the dump file. Type ".hh dbgerr004" for details
Page 1c0 not present in the dump file. Type ".hh dbgerr004" for details
Page 1c0 not present in the dump file. Type ".hh dbgerr004" for details
Page 1c0 not present in the dump file. Type ".hh dbgerr004" for details
Page 1c0 not present in the dump file. Type ".hh dbgerr004" for details
Page 1c0 not present in the dump file. Type ".hh dbgerr004" for details
Probably caused by : Pool_Corruption ( nt!ExDeferredFreePool+f3c )



Followup:     Pool_corruption
---------



0: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************



KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE (139)
A kernel component has corrupted a critical data structure.  The corruption
could potentially allow a malicious user to gain control of this machine.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A LIST_ENTRY has been corrupted (i.e. double remove).
Arg2: ffffd000255f84d0, Address of the trap frame for the exception that caused the bugcheck
Arg3: ffffd000255f8428, Address of the exception record for the exception that caused the bugcheck
Arg4: 0000000000000000, Reserved



Debugging Details:
------------------



Page 1c0 not present in the dump file. Type ".hh dbgerr004" for details
Page 1c0 not present in the dump file. Type ".hh dbgerr004" for details
Page 1c0 not present in the dump file. Type ".hh dbgerr004" for details
Page 1c0 not present in the dump file. Type ".hh dbgerr004" for details
Page 1c0 not present in the dump file. Type ".hh dbgerr004" for details
Page 1c0 not present in the dump file. Type ".hh dbgerr004" for details
Page 1c0 not present in the dump file. Type ".hh dbgerr004" for details
Page 1c0 not present in the dump file. Type ".hh dbgerr004" for details
Page 1c0 not present in the dump file. Type ".hh dbgerr004" for details
Page 1c0 not present in the dump file. Type ".hh dbgerr004" for details
Page 1c0 not present in the dump file. Type ".hh dbgerr004" for details
Page 1c0 not present in the dump file. Type ".hh dbgerr004" for details



SYSTEM_SKU:  Latitude 3540



SYSTEM_VERSION:  A10



BIOS_DATE:  01/28/2015



BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  0RV82X



BASEBOARD_VERSION:  A02



BUGCHECK_P1: 3



BUGCHECK_P2: ffffd000255f84d0



BUGCHECK_P3: ffffd000255f8428



BUGCHECK_P4: 0



TRAP_FRAME:  ffffd000255f84d0 -- (.trap 0xffffd000255f84d0)
NOTE: The trap frame does not contain all registers.
Some register values may be zeroed or incorrect.
rax=ffffc0004db33620 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=0000000000000003
rdx=ffffc00051f7c230 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=fffff803c28b66ec rsp=ffffd000255f8660 rbp=0000000000000000
 r8=ffffc0004db33da0  r9=ffffc000399aa010 r10=ffffc00051e23010
r11=0000000000000001 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe cy
nt!ExDeferredFreePool+0xf3c:
fffff803`c28b66ec cd29            int     29h
Resetting default scope



EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffd000255f8428 -- (.exr 0xffffd000255f8428)
ExceptionAddress: fffff803c28b66ec (nt!ExDeferredFreePool+0x0000000000000f3c)
   ExceptionCode: c0000409 (Security check failure or stack buffer overrun)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000001
NumberParameters: 1
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000003
Subcode: 0x3 FAST_FAIL_CORRUPT_LIST_ENTRY



CPU_COUNT: 4



CPU_MHZ: a22



CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel



CPU_FAMILY: 6



CPU_MODEL: 45



CPU_STEPPING: 1



DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  LIST_ENTRY_CORRUPT



BUGCHECK_STR:  0x139



PROCESS_NAME:  dwm.exe



CURRENT_IRQL:  1



ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000409 - The system detected an overrun of a stack-based buffer in this application. This overrun could potentially allow a malicious user to gain control of this application.



EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000409 - The system detected an overrun of a stack-based buffer in this application. This overrun could potentially allow a malicious user to gain control of this application.



EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000003



ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10240.9 amd64fre



LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff803c27d13e9 to fffff803c27c67a0



STACK_TEXT:  
ffffd000`255f81a8 fffff803`c27d13e9 : 00000000`00000139 00000000`00000003 ffffd000`255f84d0 ffffd000`255f8428 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffd000`255f81b0 fffff803`c27d1710 : 93b00001`5cfda921 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`05ab1101 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiBugCheckDispatch+0x69
ffffd000`255f82f0 fffff803`c27d08f3 : fffff803`c2a17340 ffffd001`33480180 00000000`0000000c ffffe001`b06cc180 : nt!KiFastFailDispatch+0xd0
ffffd000`255f84d0 fffff803`c28b66ec : ffffc000`49ac8680 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiRaiseSecurityCheckFailure+0xf3
ffffd000`255f8660 fffff803`c28b477d : ffffc000`4976a840 ffffc000`49ac8680 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 : nt!ExDeferredFreePool+0xf3c
ffffd000`255f86e0 fffff800`e811a219 : ffffe001`b3b6f910 ffffc000`379588c0 ffffe001`b16fc510 00000194`32306956 : nt!ExFreePoolWithTag+0x76d
ffffd000`255f87c0 fffff800`e811d440 : ffffe001`b2051bc0 00000000`00000000 ffffc000`379588c0 ffffe001`b16fb000 : dxgmms2!VIDMM_GLOBAL::CloseLocalAllocation+0x21d
ffffd000`255f87f0 fffff800`e811fc67 : ffffc000`4725c010 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : dxgmms2!VIDMM_GLOBAL::CloseOneAllocation+0x2a0
ffffd000`255f8920 fffff800`e80e1a1a : ffffd001`33480180 fffff800`e54949d8 ffffd000`00000008 ffffc000`ffffffff : dxgmms2!VIDMM_GLOBAL::CloseAllocation+0x2f
ffffd000`255f8960 fffff800`e548bcc1 : ffffc000`2dedb440 00000000`00000000 ffffc000`393608c0 ffffe001`b484c400 : dxgmms2!VidMmCloseAllocation+0x1a
ffffd000`255f89a0 fffff800`e5488621 : fffff800`e54884f0 ffffe001`b05da010 ffffe001`b05da010 00000000`00000000 : dxgkrnl!DXGDEVICE::DestroyDeferredAllocations+0x131
ffffd000`255f8b10 fffff803`c26c6c59 : fffff803`c2a17200 ffffe001`b484c2c0 ffffe001`b05da3b8 00000000`01baee23 : dxgkrnl!DxgkpDeferredDestructionWork+0x131
ffffd000`255f8b80 fffff803`c2771b75 : ff5081b9`ff5081b9 00000000`00000080 ffffe001`aba72680 ffffe001`b484c2c0 : nt!ExpWorkerThread+0xe9
ffffd000`255f8c10 fffff803`c27cb946 : ffffd001`33480180 ffffe001`b484c2c0 fffff803`c2771b34 ff5786bc`ff5685bb : nt!PspSystemThreadStartup+0x41
ffffd000`255f8c60 00000000`00000000 : ffffd000`255f9000 ffffd000`255f3000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiStartSystemThread+0x16




STACK_COMMAND:  kb



FOLLOWUP_IP: 
nt!ExDeferredFreePool+f3c
fffff803`c28b66ec cd29            int     29h



SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  4



SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!ExDeferredFreePool+f3c



FOLLOWUP_NAME:  Pool_corruption



IMAGE_NAME:  Pool_Corruption



DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0



IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.10586.420



MODULE_NAME: Pool_Corruption



BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  f3c



FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x139_3_nt!ExDeferredFreePool



BUCKET_ID:  0x139_3_nt!ExDeferredFreePool



PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0x139_3_nt!ExDeferredFreePool



ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM



FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x139_3_nt!exdeferredfreepool



FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {14bfade4-e1ed-98c0-40bb-116f20a8dfc3}



Followup:     Pool_corruption
---------
```

Do you have any suggestion on what could be the cause of these crashes?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you even need IMEI installed ?

Comment: Actually I have no idea.

Comment: You should determine if you do or not then update your question

Comment: http://forums.tweaktown.com/gigabyte/55149-intel-management-engine-interface-needed.html

Comment: I just uninstalled it. Let's see if the crashes stop

Comment: Removed Intel Management Engine Interface and Intel Rapid Storage, so far no crashes even putting in sleep mode.

Answer (score -1):

*Edit*

As the person who commented on me has pointed out, this is probably a drive issue. I stand by using the sfc.exe command to find out the OS files running that could be causing the crash.

It could be a driver trying to overwrite into memory that is should not. Fixing that could be as simple as just rotating your ram sticks.

If rotating ram doesn't work, i'd recommend using driver verifier. If you don't know what that is, here's a video url that walks you through the entire process.

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-16-WinDbg-Driver-Verifier

IME is also not necessary unless you have need for it (You'd have a personal need, not an operational need). I'm crossing my fingers that you're uninstall of it worked. Please update us if that's what solved it!

Comment: The author recently installed Windows, multiple time, SFC will not solve their problem.  This is a driver conflict.

Comment: Please run sfc.exe /scannow to see what's running when it crashes... That way we can at least narrow down what driver it could be...

Comment: SFC isn't going to detect a problem with a device driver, SFC isn't the correct tool, to determine the driver responsible for the crash. "a drive issue" or "a driver issue"?